# Is there a way to convert the string values within a string array to individual int values? C# WPF

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion, blackjack

For context, I'm making a basic BlackJack app with C# on WPF(.Net Framework).
I now have a string array for when I press a button, the cards that are handed out are dealt to both the player and dealer.

I want to use that same array, assign individual int values to the individual strings, use those to calculate the sum of the cards that are put in a listbox after pressing the button to show the sum in a label.

I've tried a lot of things and am now unsure as to how I'm going to convert the string array to int.

If you know a better/easier way to go about this, I'm definitely open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance

```
       private string[] kaartenArray = new string[52]
{
            "Klaveren Aas", "Klaveren 2", "Klaveren 3", "Klaveren 4", "Klaveren 5", "Klaveren 6", "Klaveren 7", "Klaveren 8", "Klaveren 9", "Klaveren 10", "Klaveren Boer", "Klaveren Koningin", "Klaveren Koning",
            "Ruiten Aas", "Ruiten 2", "Ruiten 3", "Ruiten 4", "Ruiten 5", "Ruiten 6", "Ruiten 7", "Ruiten 8", "Ruiten 9", "Ruiten 10", "Ruiten Boer", "Ruiten Koningin", "Ruiten Koning",
            "Harten Aas", "Harten 2", "Harten 3", "Harten 4", "Harten 5", "Harten 6", "Harten 7", "Harten 8", "Harten 9", "Harten 10", "Harten Boer", "Harten Koningin", "Harten Koning",
            "Schoppen Aas", "Schoppen 2", "Schoppen 3", "Schoppen 4", "Schoppen 5", "Schoppen 6", "Schoppen 7", "Schoppen 8", "Schoppen 9", "Schoppen 10", "Schoppen Boer", "Schoppen Koningin", "Schoppen Koning"
};

        private void KaartWaarde()
        {
                int[] kaartWaarde = Array.ConvertAll(kaartenArray, s => int.Parse(s));

                kaartWaarde[0] = 1;
                kaartWaarde[1] = 2;
                kaartWaarde[2] = 3;
                kaartWaarde[3] = 4;
                kaartWaarde[4] = 5;
                kaartWaarde[5] = 6;
                kaartWaarde[6] = 7;
                kaartWaarde[7] = 8;
                Etc............
```

This was my last attempt to convert, I wasn't sure what it was, but apparently this can't be used for what I wanted to use it for.

Klaveren, Ruiten, Harten and Schoppen are the suits. Aas means ace, etc...

Comment: why using two collections instead one collection of type which contains both information ?

Comment: Your array index already contains the information you want.  If you don't want to use zero, just put a placeholder item there.

Comment: creating class to store value and name has also other pros ... fx Aces can have alternative value ... you may add this property too ... color property - no problem

Answer (score 4):

Why not make life easier on yourself and use the power of C# and use classes e.g.,

```
class Card
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

then keep a list of class `Card`

```
List<Card> AllCards = new List<Card>(){ new Card{Name="King", Value=10},...};
```

You can expand this further by adding a Card Suit e.g.

```
class Card
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Suit{get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} of {Suit}";
    }
}
```

then have `new Card{Name="Queen", Value=10, Suit="Diamond"}`

Obviously this can be expanded by use of enumerated type for Suit or Value and use of private setters and constructor passing of properties.

Further on if you wish to use databinding in your WPF pages you can enhance the `Card` class by have it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the public properties.